# Only read numbers out of users input

Tags: c++, function, input, numbers, cin

I'm trying to write a function which only reads four ints out of a users input like this: ewzge242jfdsiii23 So it is supposed to save only 2422.
This is my code and it just gives me some weird output, if I let it cout number.
Can you maybe see my mistakes and explain why I can't do it how I did and what I could do instead? Thanks a lot!

```
    int readnumber ( ) {

   char kar, ont_kar, ont_ont_kar;
      int number;
    while (kar != '\n' ){
             cin.get (kar);
        if (kar >= '0' && kar <= '9') {
            old_kar=kar;
            old_kar = old_kar*10 + (kar - '0');
            old_old_kar = old_kar ;
        } //if
    } //while
    if (old_kar < 9999) {

        number=old_kar;
    }//if
    else {

        number=old_old_kar;
    }//else

}//readnumber
```

Comment: How do you get `2422` from the digits `2`, `4`, `2`, `2` and `3`? Shouldn't there be a `3` at the end as well?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude "which only reads four ints" By `ints` he mean `digits` I guess.

Comment: As for your problem, [read a line into a string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Then [copy the digits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) into a new string. And you're done.

Comment: All those weird var names game me a headache.

Comment: Oh I missed that requirement about four digits. Then instead of `std::copy_if`, use a [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to loop over the lines you read (or even a regular `for` loop), breaking out when the destination string is equal to four characters? And if you want an `int` value, [there are function to convert strings to that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: the number should be smaller than for example 9999, so it should not save further digits if it would be bigger.

Comment: [No loops on the surface](https://www.ideone.com/SsNOd1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks too complicated, why do you need so many variables?

Also `old_kar` and `old_old_kar` are misstyped. The function does not return, that should be the main problem.

Here's a quick simple example:

```
unsigned readnumber(int number_of_chars) {
    char ch;
    unsigned number = 0;
    while (number_of_chars > 0) {
        std::cin.get(ch);
        if ('\n' == ch)
            break;  // Stop on new line
        if (ch < '0' or ch > '9')
            continue; // Skip non-digits
        --number_of_chars; // One digit processed
        number = number * 10 + ch - '0'; // And added to the result
    }
    return number;
}
```

And here is a full version without `break` or `continue`:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cin, std::cout
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream

using namespace std;

int readnumber(int number_of_chars) {
    char ch;
    int number = 0;
    while (number_of_chars > 0) {
        std::cin.get(ch);
        if ('\n' == ch)
            return number;
        if (ch >= '0' and ch <= '9') {
            --number_of_chars;
            number = number * 10 + ch - '0';
        }
    }
    return number;
}


int main() {
    int n = readnumber(4);
    cout << "You entered: " << n << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

NB: Always compile with all warnings on, this will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Thank you very much! It looks very logically without making too much effort, I'm just sadly not allowed to use unsigned or continue.

Comment: just use int, I used unsigned because the function can not return negative number anyways. You can do without continue... will edit it in 5 minutes.